# PDO update trouble

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I'm having trouble updating a mysql database using PDO. I am not getting any error message when I execute the update query but it's not updating that database. Error reporting is on i think - self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ) - and i did get an error at the start indicating i had got a column name wrong and one about a syntax error but since fixing those I'm not getting any error messages. I've tried various things from some of the other similar queries without joy.

I have a class called Events, the constructor executes a select statement without problem. Update is a function in the class and the $array parameter being passed in is $_POST (submitted form data) - am I trying to access this $_POST data from $array the wrong way?

here is the function

```
function update ($array) {

    $this->db = mydb::getConnection();

    try {

        // prepare statement
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE gigs SET who = :who WHERE gig_id = :gig_id");

        // bind parameters
        $statement->bindParam(':gig_id', $array['gig_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(':who', $array['who'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        // execute statement
        $statement->execute();

    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        throw $ex;

    }

}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: In your `catch` block, try `echo $ex->getMessage()` to see if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I gave that a go but it's not echoing any more clues

Comment: Are you sure your `$array` keys exist and have values? Try `var_dump($array)`

Comment: Also, try catching `PDOException` just as a trial.

Comment: I just did that and it seems the keys and values exist. This is what I got...
array(12) {
  ["q"]=>
  string(3) "388"
  ["who"]=>
  string(55) "string text here"

Comment: No difference with PDOException

Comment: I seem to have a labeling error with the keys but after fixing it the problem remains

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->db)` yield?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance guys, this is working today, i'm not sure what exactly was wrong but I seem to have fixed it somehow while trying out your suggestions. Hopefully it stays this way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

- You don't need the `try ... catch` block if you are simply throwing the exception without doing anything
- I do not think the `$this->db->prepare()` works.  The chaining is fine but you should probably do `($this->db)->prepare()` or the following

  ```
  $pdo = $this->db;
  $pdo->prepare(...)
  ```

so, please try the following:

```
function update ($array) {
    $this->db = mydb::getConnection();

    // prepare statement
    $pdo = $this->db;
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE gigs SET who = :who WHERE gig_id = :gig_id");

    // bind parameters
    $statement->bindParam(':gig_id', $array['gig_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(':who', $array['who'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // execute statement
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it out but the result is the same - no update

Comment: His `mydb::getConnection()` could be a singleton, can't necessarily rule that out. As long as `$this->db` is a valid PDO object, his prepared statements should work.. Your example `($this->db)->prepare()` is may try to and instantiate that object again and is php 5.4+ only (though I'm not 100% sure on the former).

Comment: @Shane, like Rob W pointed out, could you share the result of `var_dump($array)`?

Comment: yes, it is a singleton. I have no trouble with a select statement using the same method. Basic syntax errors should be reported with the current set up - am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: @vinodadhikary sorry, the result of array dump is:
 array(12) { ["q"]=> string(3) "388" ["who"]=> string(55) "string text here"

Comment: So, is `q` supposed to be `gig_id`?  Where do you get `gig_id` from?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance guys, this is working today, i'm not sure what exactly was wrong but I seem to have fixed it somehow while trying out your suggestions. Hopefully it stays this way.